# Bond Chart Prices and Very High Yields

Tags: bonds, chart, high-yield

Two questions on bonds:

1. Why is finding stock prices and charts so easy whereas for corporate bonds is so hard? Do you know a good website like TradingView that does the same for corporate bonds (a screener that works, good charts and paper trading)?
2. On the only bond screener I have found, there are bonds with very high yields (over 1000% and up to 100000%), some of these are even triple A rated and are from reputable institutions, why is that? I know there is no free lunch, so would they pay that much in relation to price? Are these mispriced opportunities or the screener is just wrong in its computations?

Comment: Regarding the corporate bonds: is there any particular country you are interested in?

Comment: "Why is finding stock prices and charts so easy whereas for corporate bonds is so hard?" — Most bonds trade over-the-counter, not on exchanges.

Comment: A very high yield would mean a very low price, not a high price.

Comment: @Flux I wouldn't say I am interested in the country of the company that issues the bond, rather I am more interested in how good the company is and what kind of yield I can get. Why?

Comment: @98418 In the USA, FINRA provides bond price data through its [Market Data Center](https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Default.jsp). There are charts, but no screener. Note that most of the corporate bond market is inaccessible to most retail investors. Look at the trade history of a few corporate bonds, and you'll see why: most bonds are illiquid, and the typical bond transaction is in the millions of dollars.

Answer (score 2):

There is no public exchange for corporate bonds, so there is no (to my knowledge) "free" source of prices.

Also, bond can have many different characteristics that make pricing more complicated. They can be callable, puttable, convertible, etc, so pricing is not always straight-forward. A bond with a high *yield* probably means it has a low *price* since yield is a measure of how much return you can expect, and the lower the price, the more return you get back. You are right that a highly-rated company *should* have lower yields, but ratings are not always up-to-date, and there can be other reasons for high yields.  So exceptions to this would need to be examined carefully to determine why its yield is so high.

Comment: What are Mot, Euromot and Etlx then? How can we talk about a bond having a high yield if there is no "universal" way of determining its price? Couldn't different dealers have different prices for the same bond? When we see the price of a bond online is that specific to a given dealer network or what?

Comment: If different dealers had different prices for the same bond, then someone would buy the cheaper one and sell the more expensive one (which may happen). I don't know the specifics of how dealer networks work, but there is no single public "exchange" like there is for equities (in reality there are multiple exchanges, but they all converge on prices because of the same arb possibility).

Comment: To answer the second question, you'd need to post the details of the bond (ISIN, price, yield, etc.) to know if/why you're getting abnormally large yields.

Comment: In the USA, FINRA provides a free source of bond prices through its [Market Data Center](https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Default.jsp).